Ubuntu 22.04.4 Still Auto-Updates Even After Disabling
Update 2024/05/08 - based on comments (thank you!):
I have never touched the innards of
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.
Don't see  update-at-shutdown .
Here's what's in the file not commented out:
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins { *blah blah* }
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist { *blah blah* }
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "auto";

That's all of it. Remainder of contents is comments.
Have been waiting for that next update on shutdown...  :-/
Update 2024/05/07 - based on responses and comments:
By "updates on its own", I mean this:

As for the "Software & Updates" suggestion, I already had most of those settings, AND I am unable to make any changes.  Any selection is immediately put back to what is shown here:

What's more interesting is, I regularly (several times a week?) do this:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

Every time I boot, upon login, get the notification, and occasionally, upon shutdown, it begins to update on its own.  I want to fully(manually) control when and how I update the system.
Here is what I have attempted.
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d

$ cat 10periodic 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";

And:
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d

$ cat 20auto-upgrades
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";

Also:
$ systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
○ unattended-upgrades.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit unattended-upgrades.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)


see updated question

Note the time of a shutdown automatic update. Next boot, check your apt log (/var/log/apt) and syslog (/var/log/syslog) for activity at that day/time. Also after the next boot, please run ls -lah /var/lib/apt/periodic/ and post the complete output to your question above.

The option for update-at-shutdown is in the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades. Please check the file and confirm that install-at-shutdown is disabled.
